# Translating horizontally inverted quads

Tags: rotation, processing, translate-animation

A couple of days ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057243/rotating-inverting-and-translating-a-pshape-object-in-processing) about translations and rotations in Processing.

I wanted to:

- translate, invert and rotate a single quadrilateral (PShape object) multiple times
- then change the height of one of its 2 top vertices

so as the whole thing act as an articulated arm that can be bent either to the right or the left.

[image]

Thanks to the help of @Rabbid76 I was able to achieve this effect but I am now facing another issue **when translating the last 5 top horizontally inverted quads**.

[image]

When bending the object, the first 3 quads get separated from the last 5 and. And the more the bending leg is curved, the farther they get apart.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix the **translation** part (from line 65 to 68) so as the quads stay attached to each other to matter how strong the bending is.

[image]

Any suggestion regarding that matter would be also greatly appreciated.

SCRIPT

```
int W = 40;
int H = 40;
int nQuads = 8;
int xOffset = 27;

float[] p0 = {-W/2 + xOffset, -H/2};
float[] p1 = {-W/2,  H/2};
float[] p2 = {W/2, H/2};
float[] p3 = {W/2, -H/2};

PShape object;


void setup(){
    size(600, 600, P2D);
    smooth(8);
}

void draw(){

    background(255);

    // Bending to the left
    float bending = sin(frameCount*.05) * .1;
    p0[1] -= bending;

    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2);


    float minX = min( min(p0[0], p3[0]), min(p2[0], p1[0]) );
    float maxX = max( max(p0[0], p3[0]), max(p2[0], p1[0]) );

    float cptX = (minX+maxX)/2;

    //Rotation Angle
    float angle = atan2(p3[1]-p0[1], p3[0]-p0[0]);

    //Pivot Height
    float PH = p0[1] + (p3[1]-p0[1]) * (cptX-p0[0])/(p3[0]-p0[0]);


    for (int i = 0; i < nQuads; i++){

        float PivotHeight  = (i % 2 == 1) ? PH : H/2; 

        //Height translation
        if (i > 0){
          translate(0, PivotHeight);
        }

        //Rotate once every 2 quads
        if (i%2 == 1){
          rotate(angle*2);
        }

        //Height translation
        //Flip all quads except 1st one
        if (i > 0){
          translate(0, PivotHeight);
          scale(1, -1);
        }

         //NOT working --> Flipping horizontally the last 5 top QUADS
         if (i == 3){
           scale(-1, 1);
           translate(- xOffset, 0); //trying to align the quads on the X axis. Y translation is missing
           rotate(-angle*2);
         }

        object();
    }
    popMatrix();
}

void object() {

    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(p0[0], p0[1]);
    vertex(p1[0], p1[1]);
    vertex(p2[0], p2[1]);
    vertex(p3[0], p3[1]);
    endShape();
}
```

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/computing-pivot-height/7364

Comment: @KevinWorkman You seem very active when it comes to dig and find cross posts but I'd appreciate if you could help instead

Comment: Please keep in mind that the people helping you are doing so for free, in their personal time. I honestly hope you find your answer, but please be respectful of other folk's time. Posting to multiple sites is okay, but please link between the posts so we don't repeat advice you've already received. Good luck.

Comment: The [tag:translation]-tag is specifically for **language translation**, e.g. from English to German. Not for images, hence the edit was made in the tags. Please don't roll back again.

Comment: @Adriaan I understand. However I would argue that "translation" refers to a very specific function of Processing (like "rotation") and that "translate-animation" is misleading and confusing: it is NOT an animation and the term doesn't belong to the terminology used by the processing community.

Comment: @solub sure, but please do post this on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in that case, because as the tag excerpts and wiki pages currently read, this is how it stands. Translation happens to be alas used for both the mathematical, and linguistic technique, and the choice has been made for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing a workaround to my own question but won't accept it as a valid answer as I don't really understand what I'm doing and it's probably not the most efficient solution.

```
int W = 40;
int H = 40;
int nQuads = 8;
int xOffset = 27;

float[] p0 = {-W/2 + xOffset, -H/2};
float[] p1 = {-W/2,  H/2};
float[] p2 = {W/2, H/2};
float[] p3 = {W/2, -H/2};

PShape object;


void setup(){
    size(600, 600, P2D);
    smooth(8);
}

void draw(){

    background(255);

    // Bending to the left
    float bending = sin(frameCount*.05) * .3;
    p0[1] -= bending;

    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2);


    float minX = min( min(p0[0], p3[0]), min(p2[0], p1[0]) );
    float maxX = max( max(p0[0], p3[0]), max(p2[0], p1[0]) );

    float cptX = (minX+maxX)/2;

    //Rotation Angle
    float angle = atan2(p3[1]-p0[1], p3[0]-p0[0]);

    //Pivot Height
    float PH = p0[1] + (p3[1]-p0[1]) * (cptX-p0[0])/(p3[0]-p0[0]);


    for (int i = 0; i < nQuads; i++){

         float PivotHeight  = (i % 2 == 1) ? PH : H/2; 

        //Height translation
        if (i > 0){
          translate(0, PivotHeight);
        }

        //Rotate once every 2 quads
        if (i%2 == 1){
          rotate(angle*2);
        }

        //Height translation
        //Flip all quads except 1st one
        if (i > 0){
          translate(0, PivotHeight);
          scale(1, -1);
       }

         //Flipping horizontally the last 5 top QUADS
         if (i == 3){
           scale(-1, 1);
           translate(0, PivotHeight); 
           rotate(-angle*2);
           translate(0, PivotHeight);
           translate(-xOffset , H/2 - p0[1]);
         }

        object();
    }
    popMatrix();
}

void object() {

    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(p0[0], p0[1]);
    vertex(p1[0], p1[1]);
    vertex(p2[0], p2[1]);
    vertex(p3[0], p3[1]);
    endShape();
}
```

[image]